# Prisma MongoDB Array of Objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, prisma

I am trying to insert a data to MongoDB array that has value of objects with Prisma Model.
The data I'm trying to insert is a product with image, name, and description.

I have tried this method but I am getting errors.
I think my model is incorrect

```
 const addProd = await prisma.products.create({
        data: {
            csso: [
                {
                    image: req.file.filename,
                    name: req.body.name,
                    desc: req.body.desc
                }
            ]
        }
    })
```

**Here is my Model**

```
model Products {
  id    String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  csso String[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prima suggests mapping all entities to be used.

Try to do it like this:

```
model Products {
  id    String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  csso  Csso[]
}

type Csso {
  image String
  name  String
  desc  String
}
```

Comment: This creates a second document in a different collection. That's not what the OP was looking to do. It's also not very wise to create a document and it's sole purpose is related to another document. This isn't a SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `Json` not a `String`.

```
model Products {
  id    String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  csso  Json
}

const addProd = await prisma.products.create({
    data: {
        csso: {
                image: req.file.filename,
                name: req.body.name,
                desc: req.body.desc
            }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is what Marcelo pointed out. You need to use [composite types](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/composite-types)

```
model Product {
    id     String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
    name   String  @unique
    price  Float
    colors Color[]
}

enum Color {
  Red
  Green
  Blue
}
```